# Chart.JS Renders differently between plain HTML/JS/CSS to Blazor w/JSRunetime

Tags: .net-core, chart.js, blazor

I am using the same JSON object to create Chart.JS line chart.
When I use HTML/JS/CSS I get what I want.
When I try the same using Blazor with JSRunTime, it looks different and the labels are missing.
See below snapshots:

First one is with blazor, where both yAxis are on left, even if the JSON clearly states that one should be on the right.
Also The labels for both yAxis and xAxis do not show. Second pic is from simple HTML/JS/CSS with same JSON, and this renders the way I intended

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't see your screen - you should edit your question to include the Blazor code you use to render/configure/populate the chart.

Comment: Without your code only thing that I can think off that is your issue is a mismatch of versions, you are using v2 for one of them and v3 for the other. This does not work since v3 has a lot of breaking changes